# HTTP not socket web requests - D

Tags: d

How can I make **GET** and **POST** HTTP requests? I found **Socket** solution, but is it all?

```d
string host = "google.com";
ushort port = 80;

Socket listener = new TcpSocket;
    assert(listener.isAlive);
    listener.blocking = false;

listener.connect(new InternetAddress(host, port));

char[] msg;
char[] req = cast(char[]) "GET /search.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n";

listener.send(req);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [`std.net.curl`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html). It has [`get`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html#.get) and [`post`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html#.post) methods:

```d
import std.net.curl;

auto content = get("d-lang.appspot.com/testUrl2");
// --
auto content = post("d-lang.appspot.com/testUrl2", [1,2,3,4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

curl is undeniably good solution. However, that would add a new dependency to your project, right? Depending on the kind of project you work on, I advise you to use Adam Ruppe's `arsd` modules, in particular the `http` module (he is also working on http2 one as well) - https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd/blob/master/http.d . Or, perhaps if you want a framework, then vibe.d is your best option (http://vibed.org) as it has a HTTP client too. There are two vibe.d related, web development oriented, books that I recommend, and they are listed on the following page: http://vibed.org/tutorials.

UPDATE: There is a fantastic port of Python's requests package you should give a try: https://github.com/ikod/dlang-requests .

Answer (score 0):

You can using [hunt-http](https://github.com/huntlabs/hunt-http) library to request every website ::

### example for get:

```
import hunt.http;

import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    auto client = new HttpClient();

    auto request = new RequestBuilder().url("https://www.google.com").build();
    auto response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    if (response !is null)
    {
        writeln(response.getBody().asString());
    }
}
```